# Is there a way to permanently exclude the kernel from updates?

Tags: kernel, yum

I'm using Fedora and wonder if there is some way I can exclude kernel updates when I run `yum update`, until I specifically want to update the kernel.

The reason why I am concerned about this is because sometimes it requires a lot of extra research finding patches for some programs and extra time spent recompiling them to work on the new kernel.  I am thinking VMWare specifically as one example.

I wonder if there is some way for `yum update` to NOT update the kernel and only notify me that a new one is available when it goes through its routine so that I can decide to put it off until a more convenient time.  Or is this thinking likely to cause other issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
yum --exclude=kernel\* update
```

or:

```
yum -x 'kernel*' update
```

From `yum` man page:

```
-x, --exclude=package
        Exclude a specific package by name or glob from updates on all
        repositories. Configuration Option: exclude
```

And if you want to make this persistence, add a line `exclude=kernel*` to `/etc/yum.conf`:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://b
distroverpkg=centos-release
exclude=kernel*
```

When you want to update,use `--disableexcludes` option to override config in `yum.conf`:

```
yum --disableexcludes=main update
```

Comment: I believe you can also put exclude=kernel\* in /etc/yum.conf if you don't want to remember the option every time or alias it.

Comment: @Livinglifeback: Yeap, I was updating my answer when you commented.

Comment: Okay the persistant solution is what I was looking for. It works, but let's say I now think its time to update the kernel. `yum update kernel*` won't work unless I remove the exclude from yum.conf. Is there an easy way to override it when I want to?

Comment: @Octopus: Updated my answer!

Comment: Applied the same configuration to my `dnf.conf` on Fedora. I'm curious, will I get a new kernel update when I will upgrade to the next Fedora major release?